# Null pointer exception in kafka schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

When tried to start the kafka producer with avro schema , getting null pointer exception always. please help.

```
~$ sudo  kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic employeedetails --property parse.key=true --property value.schema= '{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}' 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1225)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1032)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1020)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.init(AvroMessageReader.java:136)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:42)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
```

Comment: Is it typo?
Extra space between `value.schema` can you remove and try.

Comment: Agreed. Spaces matter. Or in this case, no space. The error is saying that `value.schema=''`, which is parsed as null, then you're giving another random string argument to the producer script